# Cambio de orden en registros de una tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta:
tengo una tabla llamada linea_bloque con una columna llamada orden.
Lo que Quisiera hacer es una query  que la posición que tenga el registro con un update intercambien el orden, es decir, si el registro 5 quiero que sea el 8, bueno que en la columna orden el 5 se guarde en el 8 y viceversa.
Espero haberme explicado.

la primera parte la logro así:

```sql
UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=5 WHERE orden=8;
```

Pero no se como después decirle que donde estaba el 5 sea el 8.

Comment: Lo suyo es que uses un valor temporal intermedio, por ejemplo: 8->-1, 5->8, -1->5, así siempre sabrás los que te quedan pendientes. Pero, ¿para qué habrías algo así? Lo habitual es reordenar por otro criterio y sobreescribir el campo `orden` con el nuevo valor que le corresponda... No lo sé, danos algún detalle más para poder ayudarte...

Comment: Es que cuando muestro la consulta en mi SELECT tengo un ORDER BY "orden"
 y la idea es que ese orden sea modificable. Me explico?

Comment: ¿Y por qué quieres cambiar el orden? ¿Cuál es el nuevo criterio? Desde luego `orden` ya no puede ser...

Comment: Pense usar le ID de cada uno para poder colocar el nuevo order en su lugar seria factible? 

UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=5 WHERE ID=???;
UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=8 WHERE ID=???;

Dos UPDATE es solucionable?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es ordenar por `ID`, usa `ORDER BY ID` y no te compliques. Por lo que comentas, parece que quieres hacer un `UPDATE tabla SET orden=ID` para lo que no hace falta `WHERE`

Comment: No,no quiero ordenar por ID sino por la columna orden y con ello es que quiero que ese orden sea modificable, por como dije al princpio que por ejemplo el registro 5 ya no se muestre de 5 sino de 8 y el 8 de 5... solo que el primer movimiento es sencillo pero el segundo no lo se dar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, da la sensación de que buscas un valor temporal intermedio, por ejemplo `-1`, para que no se te mezclen los datos y obtener algo así:

```
UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=-1 WHERE orden=8;

UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=8 WHERE orden=5;

UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=5 WHERE orden=-1;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Comment: Exacto, eso entiendo en mi nivel jejejejej muchas gracias... Ahora si se puede cerrar la pregunta como resuelta. Gracias

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner los números en variables y usar algo como:

```
UPDATE linea_bloque SET num1 = num2, num2=num1
```

También podrías hacer un join a la misma tabla para mantener los valores y usarlo para actualizar el segundo, o tambien puedes declarar variables auxiliares si las necesitas.

Comment: Perfecto, mas simple no puede ser... y yo pensando en select anidados y cosas rarar... thk... Un Jr. Agragadecido.

Pero despues hago dos Update?

num=5
num2=8
UPDATE linea_bloque SET orden=num1 WHERE orden=num2

Comment: Honestamente no lo se, pero te agradezco mucho si la puedes dar por cerrada y me confirmas como se hace para futuras oportunidades, gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Se hace con las simpbolos a la izquierda de cada respuesta lo acabo de ver.

Comment: Muchas gracias!